# Maven: can one parent pom.xml import <pluginManagement> from another parent pom.xml

Tags: maven, plugins, import, pom.xml, parent-pom

I have 2 POMs for 2 separate multi-module parents:

```
CorePOM/pom.xml

SpectPOM/pom.xml
```

The children of SpecPOM use children of CorePOM, but I do not want to make SpecPOM a child of CorePOM.

I am using `<dependencyManagement>` import thus:

```
<dependencyManagement>        
    <dependencies>

    <!-- Use import to sync versions with CorePOM -->   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example.multi</groupId>
        <artifactId>CorePOM</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>    
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**Q: Is there an equivalent import strategy for `<pluginManagement>` so I can sync versions of plugins ?**

If not, how can I avoid repeating plugin versions in both CorePom and SpecPOM ?

Comment: Give them a common parent which contains the pluginManagement definitions (so call corporate pom like)..

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for suggestion but I don't want to give them a common parent (although it would work). I need the CorePOM to be completely agnostic to SpecPOM, and to have no coupling to it.

Comment: Vote for https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5102 or more specific https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5588